# React sticky footer moves up when there is less content on the page

Tags: css, reactjs

My web app's footer won't stay at the bottom when there is less content on the page.  I'm stuck and not sure where to go from here.  Can someone help me with a footer that will stay at the bottom of the page and below any content?

```
const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Redirect to='/home' />)} />
                <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/films" component={Films} />
                <Route path="/markets" component={Markets} />
                <Route path="/news" component={News} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </div>
    </Router>
)
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You could say that the `body` should have a height as big as the screen. `body { height: 100vh; ... }`

Comment: @Tholle that didn't work :(

Comment: can you create demo so we can have a look

Comment: @Rahul I'm not sure how to do that but I added a screenshot of how it looks

Answer (score 1):

Sticky won't work because the div is "treated as **relatively positioned** until its containing block crosses a specified threshold."

Try this:
position: absolute,
bottom: 0

Comment: Do I put that in the CSS under body?

Comment: You can create an element selector for the div in the css file (similar to the body selector), or you can add it inline to the div -- <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">. It looks like you may be using React, so they're are also some libraries that allow you to add styles to the js files, e.g. Material UI with "withStyles" and "classNames" components for a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Put your footer as position: absolute, and on body put position: relative, so your footer's position is relative to your body.

Then bottom should be 0 or 100, I forgot but either one should make the footer stick to the bottom.

Comment: Do I put bottom under body or footer?

Comment: your footer should have "bottom: 0;" because that is what you want at the bottom of your page.